# How to swap between different postgres databases, ensuring that there's no downtime

Tags: postgresql, update, migration

I have some database A, and some operations take a while to process which can cause downtime. I'd like to prevent this, and have considered the following approach:

1. create B - a clone of database A
2. carry out changes required on B
3. once changes are completed and checked change app URLs from `database-A` to `database-B`

Problem here is that after Step 1, data is still being added to database A, meaning that by the time Step 3 is completed `database-B` will be out of sync with `database-A`.

So I'm wondering whether there's an approach which will prevent this, and if so - how might I go about it?

There might be a well written explanation for this already, it seems like it would be common, but I'm not aware of the correct terms/literature.

Comment: You should generally look to improve the root cause of "*some operations take a while to process which can cause downtime*" instead of trying to work around them by maintaining a copy of the database. You'll find there's a potential tradeoff between how up to date the second database can be vs performance overhead you'll add to the databases (so you'll be back at square one). And if you don't fix the root problem of your performance issues then there's no reason you won't see the same issues on the copied database as well. In any case, one industry term you're looking for is *replication*.

Comment: I agree with J.D.: you should fix the root cause that causes the downtime. Rather than working around it. What kind of "downtime" are we talking about anyway? Important tables are getting locked? The server is overloaded? You might want to share the code that causes this "downtime"

Comment: What is the nature of "changes required on B"?